# Запрет HTML5 Notifications

Tags: javascript, html5

Можно ли запретить плагинам создать HTML5 Notifications на странице?

Comment: что за плагины имеются ввиду?

Comment: Яндекс Советник.

Comment: то есть имеется ввиду расширение для браузера?

Comment: Да, именно.....

Comment: для хрома можно настройки изменить: chrome://settings/content/notifications в яндекс.браузере наверняка что-то похожее будет

Comment: С помощью JS это возможно? Врядли. Сайт мой. Яндекс Советник уводит посетителя у меня предлагая цену дешевле. А мы работает по фикс цене и недобросовестные дилеры снижают цену и получают моего посетителя.

Comment: Устанавливая расширение, запрашиваются разрешения, в т. ч. и уведомления. Если юзер согласен и установил - отозвать разрешение можно только удалением/отключением расширения, что логично.

Comment: Это понятно, но я не хочу чтобы работал у меня Яндекс советник. В сайт вкладываются большие деньги, и тут недобросовестный дилер однодневка получает МОЕГО посетителя..

Comment: в данном случае ничего нельзя сделать. К тому же не все пользователи пользуются этим советником

Comment: [тут](http://sa1nikov.ru/blokiruem-sovetnik-yandeks-marketa-sajte-internet-magazina/) три ссылки на какие-то скрипты типа для блокировки советника, уж не знаю, насколько это безопасно и действенно (даже открывать страшно). Но если Вы отчаялись - можете попробовать их препарировать. Ну или просто использовать в чистом виде.